# Upgrade CouchDB 1.0.1 to 1.4

Tags: couchdb

I would like to know what are the steps to upgrade an existing CouchDb 1.0.1 installation with databases to the latest CouchDb version 1.4?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not aware  of an automatic installer that does this for you there is a very [handy build tool for couchDb](https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb) on github.

It allows you to install multiple versions of CouchDB at once. If you don't require a particular version you can simply remove it.

There is one important thing to keep in mind though. While your data won't corrupt between upgrades, CouchDB on disk format is still evolving and the existing format may be incompatible between versions. For example [check out the breaking changes between 1.1.0 and 1.2.0](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Breaking_changes#Changes_Between_1.1.0_and_1.2.0).

If you are planning to use several versions of CouchDB at once it would be best if you copied you data and just put it in the database_dir for that version.